# How do I make my own Linux system call output to the process's terminal instead of to the kernel log?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I wrote a system call that outputs system information to the kernel log. Here is an example program that invokes my system call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int ret = syscall(351, 2);
    printf(“%d\n”, ret);
    if(ret == 2)
        printf(“the first syscall is success!\n);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I want to see the output differently.  Instead of using `dmesg` to read the kernel log, I want the system call to output the result directly to the terminal (of the calling process in the simplest case, or even just to its standard output).

How can I arrange to do that?

Comment: Which terminal? Put another way, how would the system call know where to send its output?

Comment: Don't skimp on bytes; feel free to put your actual question in the Question...

Comment: I wrote a system call that outputs system informations. I want to see the output now, but instead of using dmesg, I want to output the result directly to the terminal.

Comment: If your syscall uses `printk` switch to tty and do `dmesg -n8`, it modifies some files in `/proc` under the hood - you will now see the output.

Comment: ... or alternatively use something like `console=ttyS0,115200` if your hardware has UART

Comment: So I have to change the code of my system caller? Is there any other way to not change the code?

Comment: I didn't say anything about modifying the code